# Python and Plotly offline: create (empty) graph and add traces with for-loop

Tags: python, plotly, diagram

I am new to programming and I have spent a lot of time looking for a solution, but I can't seem to get it right.
I have some measurement data sets stored in a dictionary. I want to create a graph with plotly where all curves from measured data are shown. I am trying to create an empty graph and then iterating through the dictionary and add two columns of the two stored dataFrames as traces to the graph for each key.

What am I doing wrong or how can I do it in another way?

```
import plotly as py
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go    

figure1 = go.Figure()

for key in dictofdf:
 trace1 = go.Scatter(
                      y=df_1['force'], 
                      x=df_1['displacement'], 
                      mode='line',
                      marker=go.Marker(color='rgb(255, 127, 14)'),
                      name='load'
                      )

    trace2 = go.Scatter(
                      y=df_2['force'], 
                      x=df_2['displacement'], 
                      mode='line',
                      marker=go.Marker(color='rgb(55, 137, 3)'),
                      name='unload'
                      )

    figure1.append_trace(trace1,1,1)
    figure1.append_trace(trace2,1,1)

py.offline.iplot(figure1, filename='force-displacement-data', image='jpeg')
```

With the code I have so far, I get the error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
 last) <ipython-input-42-4ea5d9b8a638> in <module>()
      50                       )
      51 
 ---> 52     figure1.append_trace(trace1,1,1)
      53     figure1.append_trace(trace2,1,1)
      54 

 C:\Users\xxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\graph_objs.py
 in append_trace(self, trace, row, col)
     914                             "Note: the starting cell is (1, 1)")
     915         try:
 --> 916             ref = grid_ref[row-1][col-1]
     917         except IndexError:
     918             raise Exception("The (row, col) pair sent is out of range. "

 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `append_trace` in Plotly works for [subplots](https://plot.ly/python/subplots/) but not for regular `Figure`s.
- You are iterating over your dictionary keys, but you never use one of the keys, you are plotting the same values for each key. In the example below `key` is used to `name` the traces.

[image]

```
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

figure1 = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)

dictofdf = {'measurement1': {'df_1': {'displacement': [1, 2, 3], 
                                      'force': [1, 3, 6]}, 
                             'df_2': {'displacement': [1, 3, 6], 
                                      'force': [5, 7, 9]}
                            }, 
            'measurement2': {'df_1': {'displacement': [1, 4, 5], 
                                      'force': [8, 10 , 12]}, 
                             'df_2': {'displacement': [1, 4, 6], 
                                      'force': [7, 8, 9]}
                            }
           }
for key in dictofdf:
    trace1 = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
                      y=dictofdf[key]['df_1']['force'], 
                      x=dictofdf[key]['df_1']['displacement'], 
                      mode='line',
                      marker=plotly.graph_objs.Marker(color='rgb(255, 127, 14)'),
                      name='{}: load'.format(key)
                      )

    trace2 = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
                      y=dictofdf[key]['df_2']['force'], 
                      x=dictofdf[key]['df_2']['displacement'], 
                      mode='line',
                      marker=plotly.graph_objs.Marker(color='rgb(55, 137, 3)'),
                      name='{}: unload'.format(key)
                      )

    figure1.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)
    figure1.append_trace(trace2, 1, 2)
plotly.offline.iplot(figure1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will look for some other possibility then to make this plot, if it doesn't work in plotly. When I try the code you kindly suggested, I get the following error: `...
---> 37                       y=dictofdf[key][['df_1']['force']],
     38                       x=dictofdf[key][['df_1']['displacement']],
     39                       mode='line',

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: Just tried the posted code again, it should work. In your snippet there are double brackets. Make sure that you are slicing your dictionary/list correctly.

Comment: Hm, ok... I inserted the double brackets after I got the error message, to see if that helps. I forgot to delete them before I posted the code here.

Comment: I found my mistake: In my dictionary, the names of the dataframes (df_1 and df_2) are not stored. I am accessing it with `dictofdf[key][1]['force']`now and it works. And I am generating the plot with mathplotlib now and I get the result that I wanted.